# (Angular) Enable HTML5 mode

Tags: angular, apache, passenger

I am trying to deploy my website at OVH. It is a Web application based on Nodejs, created with ANGULAR6.
I have many difficulties in deploying it.

As you can see on my domain ([www.memoreasy.fr](http://www.memoreasy.fr/)) I have an error at the level of  "Initialize language runtime " (In the menu  "Detailed diagnostics ")
That's when I read [this](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/).
He speaks at a moment "is turn on HTML5 mode in your main Angular module's config block"
What is the "main Angular module's". If it's "app.module.ts", how should I do to integrate the code he proposes???

I know the author doesn't speak exactly about my problem, but I have been looking for a solution to my problem for a long time. 
If you think it has no relation to my problem, can you help me decrypt the error.
Thanks in advance.

PS : Sorry for spelling errors, I'm learning english

Comment: The error does not look to have anything to do with Angular. A guess would be that the server is configured to respond with the index.html file for all requests, and this prevents the browser from loading the js files.

Comment: actually i call from my server only indexe.html. I should not?

Comment: Not for `.js` requests. When the browser asks for a JS file, but receives an HTML file, it's not gonna work.

Comment: The first file I call is indexe.html it is he who does the link with the other file in javascript. So at first I call html and not js.  The rest I don't control